# Is there a topic or service to know when visual odometry estimation is lost in RTAB-MAP?

Tags: kinect, ros, odometry

I am using rtabmap to estimate odometry from visual slam. When odometry is lost, the rtabmapviz screen becomes red. I am looking for one way to know when I lose odometry in my code e.g. a topic to subscribe or something like that.

Thanks for your help

(edit)

I am using ROS kinetic and the following launch files:

```
roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch depth_registration:=true

roslaunch rtabmap_ros rtabmap.launch localization:=true rtabmapviz:=false rviz:=true
```

Comment: What are you currently using? Are you using one of the rtabmap_ros package nodes? Which one specifically? Which version of ros? 
This would help answer your question.

Comment: There is also a forum for questions for rtabmap: http://official-rtab-map-forum.67519.x6.nabble.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, I assume you're using the rtabmap_ros pkg, specifically one of the [Visual Camera/Lidar Odometry nodes](https://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#Visual_and_Lidar_Odometry). They all publish the topic `odom` `(nav_msgs/Odometry)` and the topic `odom_info` [`(rtabmap_ros/OdomInfo)`](http://docs.ros.org/api/rtabmap_ros/html/msg/OdomInfo.html). In the `rtabmap_ros/OdomInfo` msg, is the element `bool lost`, which reports if the current odometry is lost or not. 
Also, the null transform is published on the topic `odom` instead of the (lost) odometry (by default, param option).